# Cannot get the `name` claim from IdentittyServer4, when the client is written in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, owin, identityserver4

I authenticate a user to a ASP.NET (.NET Framework) site using IdentityServer4 (separate application written in .NET Core).

Everything works fine, but the `name` claim is never returned.

If the client was written in .NET Core, there seems to be this `GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint` property (assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect, Version=3.1.3.0`):

```
        services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                options.Authority = Configuration["AppSettings:IdentityServerUrl"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

                options.ClientId = Configuration["AppSettings:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AppSettings:ClientSecret"];
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true; // <<<<<<<<<<<---
            ....
```

However, in .NET Framework, I have no such property. All I have is this code (extension assembly: `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect v3.1.0.0`):

```
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            Authority = identityServerUrl,
            RedirectUri = appUrl + "/signin-oidc",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = appUrl + "/signout-callback-oidc",
            ClientId = "clientId",
            ClientSecret = @"secret",
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseTypes.CodeIdToken,
            Scope = "openid profile offline_access",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
        });
```

I have tried various things on the client and on the identity server, but nothing seems to help.

Can someone tell me how I can get this claim inside my token?

I am getting other claims, but it seems to skip calling the user info endpoint on IdentityServer, and that's why this user claim is not there.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement IPorfileService interface for .NET

read: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/reference/profileservice.html

and : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/dn277201(v%3Dvs.120)

I hope that helps you ! :)

Later edit:

```
 var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
       {
           Authority = OidcAuthority,
           ClientId = OidcClientId,
           ClientSecret = OidcClientSecret,
```

---

```
          GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
```

---

```
           PostLogoutRedirectUri = OidcRedirectUrl,
           RedirectUri = OidcRedirectUrl,
           ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
           Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId
       };
       app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
```

Comment: I have this interface implemented. But it is not called for some reason. My guess is that this missing property is the cause. I have another client, written in .NET Core, and everything works OK for it. But not for the .NET Framework client. Both clients have the same scopes defined on the IdentityServer4 side, so it should be working the same, if there weren't those client implementation differences.

Comment: Then I think is a configuration issue.

Comment: check this : https://docs.openathens.net/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=2228523

Comment: Yes, that looks promising, although it uses a 3rd party library. It is weird that Microsoft did not add this property in their own implementation. I have tried the library now (with the `GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint ` property set to `true`) but it still doesn't return the `name` claim. I will try again soon. Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to work either. I am not sure why, but nothing in the two interface implementations (`IProfileService` and `IMembershipClaimsService`) is being called, except for the `IProfileService.IsActiveAsync()`. So, either the missing `GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint` property was not the only fault, or the library (OpenAthens) is not working properly.

Comment: Check that Library .. and Debug .NET auth .. step by step .. Good luck and perseverance :D And tell me what you discover, I still think is something un-configured or package incompatibility with your .NET version ..

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add this to your client, to fix the mapping between that Microsoft consider to be the name and what Identity Server consider to be the name claim.

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
    RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
};
```

Comment: I have tried this too afterwards, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem. But it seems to be one part of the puzzle.

Comment: Do check in Fiddler and explore the data that you get from IdentityServer, just to verify that the name claim is actually returned to the client.